# Why can I concatenate 2 strings but not a string and a floating value?

Tags: python

This is some code I have been trying to do and as soon as I remove the `" "` from the character age the code doesn't work could someone please explain what I have done wrong and how I can fix it?

```
character_name = "Tom"
character_age = "50.86798"
is_male = False
print("There was once a man named " + character_name +  ",")
print("he was " + character_age + " years old")

character_name = "Mike"
print("He really liked the name " + character_name + ",")
print("but he didn't like being {0}.".format(character_age))
```

Comment: What goes wrong? What is your expected output, and what are you getting?

Comment: @Sudhan, what if you use f-strings? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals

Comment: Instead of print("he was " + character_age + " years old")
Try this print("he was " , character_age , " years old")
If you can tell the exact error then clear resolution can be provided.

Comment: You cannot operate on `float` and `str` using `+`. You can use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method) as on line 9.

Comment: Make sure to write out a relevant title. If you want to specify that you don't understand types / are new to Python, then maybe do that by adding a quick sentence in the body paragraph, however make sure that the title is very clearly reflecting what your actual question is. What is going wrong? What error are you getting? For more info about how to ask a good question, check out the ["how to ask" page.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

With the quotations, `character_age` is a string. Without the quotations, `character_age` is a float (floating-point number). When concatenating values (think: adding, combining, summing, etc.), a general rule of thumb is that only like values can be concatenated. Thus, when running this line:

```py
print("he was " + character_age + " years old")
```

an exception will be raised if `character_age` is not a string.

---

If you want to run the code with `character_age` as a float, here are a few possible solutions (there may be, and probably are, more):

1. Convert `character_age` to a string

This would involve calling the Python built-in `str()` function and passing `character_age`. This will return the float stored in `character_age` in its string representation:

```py
character_age = 50.86798
...
print("he was " + str(character_age) + " years old")
```

2. Use string formatting to format `character_age` into the string

Use whichever style of string formatting you like best, whether it be C-style string formatting, the `str.fomat()` method, or f-strings:

```py
character_age = 50.86798
...
print("he was %s years old" % character_age)
print("he was {} years old".format(character_age))
print(f"he was {character_age} years old")
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically when you are giving the double quotes the compiler is treating the variable character_age as string.

```
print("There was once a man named " + character_name +  ",")
```

So in the above line the plus(+) sign means to concatenate the different string values and show in as s new string without making any changes to the variable.

But while you are removing the double quotes, its treating the variable character_age as float. And additionally for the compiler, the meaning of plus(+) sign before a variable of type integer or float or double is to make addition arithmetic operation. But logically, we can't perform addition operation with one string and one float. That's why it's throwing error if you are removing the double quotes.

My suggested code will be,

```
character_name = "Tom"
character_age = 50.86798
is_male = False
print("There was once a man named " + character_name +  ",") # Here i have converted the veriable type float to string temporarily not permanent
print("he was " + str(character_age) + " years old")
```

Comment: Did you try running this code? First off, you would get a `NameError` exception because the function `string()` is not defined. Second off, this wouldn't solve the original problem, because the float `character_age` cannot be concatenated with the strings `"he was "` and `" years old"`. You don't need `character_name` as a string because _it already is one_. You need to call the function on `character_age`, since that is what's causing the issue.

Comment: The function is `str()`, not `string()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of type mismatch when you're using addition operators. Over here:

```
print("he was " + character_age + " years old")
```

what you are doing when you remove the `'"'` is you're turning the character age into a float instead of a string, and you cannot add floats to strings without some conversion, like `str()`.

This seems to be a very fundamental problem, so I highly recommend you learn Python a little more deeply to understand.

Comment: im really new to this just started today 

if you could recommend a tutorial i could learn from i would greatly appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

In the first code snippet, character_age is of float datatype. You cannot add a float to a string. That's like doing: "abc" + 12.34, which throws an error.

```
character_age = 50.86798
print(type(character_age))
print("HELLO " + character_age + " WORLD" )
```

But, if I added quotes to the same data, it becomes a string datatype. Python treats it as a str and not float. Hence, "abc" + "12.34" would result in "abc12.34", ie. concatenation.

```
character_age = "50.86798"
print(type(character_age))
print("HELLO " + character_age + " WORLD" )
```